Reduce Execution Time of Combining my DTR files
I am trying to combine data of these sheets (found in this LINK : text) to a new spreadsheet, but it takes more than the execution time limit. I tried other remedies (batch processing) but it didnt work. Below is my code:
function mergeDataFromSheets() {
  const folderId = "16jQGy_NZJWazugBTfkv48s-egT48RsRI";
  const masterSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const newSpreadsheet = masterSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Combined_Data");
  const targetCell = masterSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Month").getRange("Q3").getValue();
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  
  const existingData = newSpreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const existingKeys = new Set(existingData.map(row => row[0])); // Assuming first column has unique keys
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    const sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetCell);

    if (sourceSheet) {
      const lastRow = sourceSheet.getRange("C3:C").getValues().filter(String).length + 2;
      const dataRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A3:J" + lastRow);
      const dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

      dataValues.forEach((row) => {
        const key = row[0]; // Assuming first column has unique keys
        if (existingKeys.has(key)) {
          // Update existing row
          const rowIndex = existingData.findIndex(existingRow => existingRow[0] === key) + 1;
          newSpreadsheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
        } else {
          // Append new row
          newSpreadsheet.appendRow(row);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}


I tried batch processing, spreadsheet flush, etc, but they did not work. Please help me.

DTR folder is empty

There is a few things you can do to optimize your code:
Requests to the any external service including SpreadsheetApp make your code slow, so it's recommended to reduce the amount of repeated requests (like the ones in your while cycle) - see Best Practices.
Another thing you can do is log the number of columns and rows in your sheet.
A common problem is that the sheet contains a significant amount of empty rows and columns that increase your detected data range and consequently apply the subsequent calls to a bigger range than necessary. See getLastColumn(), getMaxRows() & getMaxColumns()
